# Simple jQuery not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, web

This simple jQuery code isn't running.
Using Chrome, Javascript enabled.

```
<html>

<body>
    <h1>Click for info</h1>
    <p>Here is the extra information!</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready({

            $("p").hide();

            $("h1").click(function(){
                $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Thanks for any help you can give :)

Comment: Works http://jsfiddle.net/e4RvB/ your ready is missing the function()

Comment: not running?  how do you know that? can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5):

`$(document).ready({` should be `$(document).ready(function() {`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("p").hide();

    $("h1").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```